# How do I import a PowerShell AzureRM module for use by a pipeline task

Tags: powershell, task, devops

In my build pipe line am using azure powershell task version 4, I am trying to get get storage key which uses `Get-AzureRmstorageAccountKey`  cmdlet. the tasks fails with an error "is not recognized as the name of cmdlet"

How do i install AzureRM module? can az and AzureRM used on the same agent? Can someone help here

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it worked for me.. Do give it a try :

Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName *yourresourcegroup* -AccountName *yourstorageaccount*.Value[0]

Please verify it if it works for you..
Thanks !